# Ranking python dictionary by percentile

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

If i have a dictionary that records the count frequency of random objects:

```
dict = {'oranges': 4 , 'apple': 3 , 'banana': 3 , 'pear' :1, 'strawberry' : 1....}
```

And I want only the keys that are in the top 25th percentile by frequency, how would i do that ? Especially if it's a very long tail list and a lot of records will have the same count.

Comment: what have you tried so far?  Can you give an example of the output you want?  (the question is potentially ambigious)

Comment: I essentially just want the keys that fall into the top 25th percentile by frequency count. IE if the top 25th percentile cutoff is 5 objects then only the keys that have 5 or more objects. I tried calculating the top25th percentile cutoff then only taking the keys with >= that value. but because a lot of keys have the same value it messes that method up.

Comment: `sorted(di.items(), key=lambda t:t[1], reverse=True)` and then take a slice of  the number of items comprising 1/4 of the total.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object and exploit its [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method to return the keys with the highest frequency up to the required percentile.

For the 25th percentile, divide the length of the dictionary by 4 and pass that value to `most_common`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> dct = {'oranges': 4 , 'apple': 3 , 'banana': 3 , 'pear' :1, 'strawberry' : 1}
>>> c = Counter(dct)
>>> [tup[0] for tup in c.most_common(len(dct)//4)]
['oranges']
```

Note that potential elements in that percentile with equal frequencies will be selected *arbitrarily*.